# What happens if jwt refresh_ttl expires while user logged in and have active session?

Tags: laravel, authentication, jwt

1.Implementing api authentication using *tymondesigns/jwt-auth* in a Laravel 8.x project. Testing the login and protected routes with access_token stored in cookies and implemented an autorefresh middleware if the token expired.To test it put  the *ttl*  to 2 minutes and *refresh_ttl* to 5 minutes.But when i refresh the token after 3 minutes assuming the refresh_ttl also gets updated&prolonged, after 2 minutes i can't refresh it,gives *TokenExpiredException* .Is it the expected behavior? What if a user having activity and suddenly the refresh_ttl expires and gets redirected to login?

2.All other similar threads mention the use of explicit refresh_token(if i understand correctly) but according to *jwt-auth* docs

```
$refreshed = JWTAuth::refresh(JWTAuth::getToken());
```

it uses the old token even if it expired already and not any other extra *$refresh_token* value (maybe under the hood don't know).But where is it?